# Why this HTML site not working only on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, testing, cross-browser

I've developed this website and hosted it on Godaddy. I've checked all browser compatibility. It is working fine on all devices (Win, Android, MacBook, iMac) except iPhone. What can be the problem?
Is there anyone who can find the problem?

https://samana.tech/

Comment: discard Safari if possible, and have a try by Chrome.

Comment: bro, discard means?

Comment: use Chrome instead, Safari goes wrong sometimes.